# Inner Class Instantiate Clarification

Tags: java, swing, instantiation, inner-classes

I don't understand a feature of the inner class CHameleon. I don't get what line 8 in theory means.

I think it means to produce a duplicate version of JFrame that will be accessed outside of the inner class, in order to manipulate the intended JFrame object.

Edit: Code brings a null pointer exception error because JFrame object is never referenced. 
Solution: modify JFrame frame to final JFrame frame.

This brings up the question on what if there were multiple JFrames?

For example, if I had a class garden with different veggies, and I created an inner class colorsplat that colors these veggies. Is the only solution to create specific classes that target specfic veggies? So to answer my own question, in the case of multiple JFrames, they would appear as different kinds of classes, my case?

```
public class LabelsButtonsPanelsandSnakes {

public static void main(String[] args){
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test"); 

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();  //menubar  
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");

    JMenuItem chameleon = new JMenuItem("Change Color"); 

    class CHameleonaction implements ActionListener{ //inside class opens 
        JFrame frameHolder;                          //line 8
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(112,253,95));
        }
    }                                                //inside class ends 
    chameleon.addActionListener(new CHameleonaction()); 

    menuBar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the `frameHolder` variable either. That just is wrong and looks like it will lead to a NullPointerException.

Comment: That is right. It appears my question is instead how to bridge a JFrame object from the outer class into the inner class for manipulation.

Comment: This is basically just bad design... there is no reason for a nested class here. Just use an anonymous ActionListener class implementation and make the frame you need to access final (if you really need it). If you want me to post the details, let me know.

Comment: If your code that you're asking about is generating an exception, it would be wise and polite to *tell us* about this in your question.

Comment: As per may answer, your above problem could be solved by making `frame` a `final` variable: `final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test"); `, and then referencing frame from within your ActionListener and getting rid of the frameHolder variable. But regardless, your code design is off.

Comment: Please note edit to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing way too much within your main method, and most of this code belongs elsewhere since the main method should be used to mainly create your *main* objects and start them running, but little else. As noted in my comment, your current code looks to lead you to a NullPointerException since you're trying to call a method on a field that never appears to have been initialized. I'm OK with your using an inner class for simple listener interfaces, and as noted, an anonymous inner class would work fine, but you must do this with care. If you need to refer to an outer class variable you have a few options:

- If the outer variable is a field rather than a local variable, the inner class can directly reference it.
- If it is a local variable, it must be declared *final*.
- Most Swing listeners have an XxxEvent parameter that returns the source of the event via `getSource()` and this can often lead you to a non-inner class *reference*.

---

For example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo2 extends JPanel {
   private static final Color NEW_COLOR = new Color(112,253,95);
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

   public Foo2() {
      JMenuItem chameleon = new JMenuItem(new ChangeColorAction("Change Color")); 
      JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
      menu.add(chameleon);
      menuBar.add(menu);
   }

   public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
      return menuBar;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class ChangeColorAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ChangeColorAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         setBackground(NEW_COLOR);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Foo2 mainPanel = new Foo2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setJMenuBar(mainPanel.getMenuBar());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```